# Using wildcards in mysql fulltext search phrase

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, wildcard, phrase

I'm using mysql 5.7 and am having trouble using a wildcard character in a fulltext query.

I want to use the search phase "cleft palate" and have it also include matches for the plural version "cleft palates".

The 2 queries below return the same exact results:

```
select * 
from contents 
where match(contents.content) against('+("cleft palate")' in boolean mode)
```

And

```
select * 
from contents 
where match(contents.content) against('+("cleft palate*")' in boolean mode)
```

Note the wildcard (*)

Both these query are leaving out results for "cleft palates"

Is there a way to use the wildcard character within a phrase in a fulltext query?

Comment: Where did you get the information that the FTS supports wildcards?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: You use double quotes. *A phrase that is enclosed within double quote (") characters matches only rows that contain the phrase **literally, as it was typed.*** I.e inner asterisk is NOT wildcard, it is a literal char.

Comment: Right. Given that statement, I would expect the latter query to return no results because it's doing a literal search and there are no asterisks in the data.

The issue is if I remove the double quotes, then I get results for rows that contains the word "cleft" or starts with "palate". I get too many results. I need it to match rows that contain the phrase starting with "cleft palate".. Perhaps this is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: You may use FTS in the subquery and then refine your search using LIKE or REGEXP search.

Comment: Yeah I think that is the only way to achieve what I need. Thanks!